# What method uses "diverge probability" in RNA-Seq differential expression analysis?

Tags: r, rna-seq, differential-expression

I am replicating differential expression analysis from a paper ([here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325322361_Overexpression_of_VaWRKY14_increases_drought_tolerance_in_Arabidopsis_by_modulating_the_expression_of_stress-related_genes)) on RNA-Seq data. I extracted the regulated genes using `DESeq2::results` with a threshold of 1 for log2 fold change and 0.05 for the p-value. The results are very different from that of the paper. The paper does not mention much information about their statistical methods except for this paragraph:

> Finally, the libraries were sequenced using the BGISEQ-500 platform. Differentially expressed genes were identified based on fold change ≥ 2 and diverge probability ≥ 0.8. The functional categories of the differently expressed genes and the pathway were obtained using MapMan as the classification source.

Now, I have no idea what they mean by "diverge probability" but it looks like another method to get the regulated genes. My questions are:

**Question 1:** What could be the method they are using in their analysis?

**Question 2:** Are the results from the "diverge probability" method different from the ones we get using `DESeq2::results`?

**Question 3:** If the answer to Question 2 is yes, how do we get from one to the other?

I appreciate any insights or experiences you can share regarding this approach. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm pretty informed about stats but haven't a clue what "diverge probabilities" are. Are you referring to Kullback–Leibler divergence by any chance? Whilst I understand the question, at present its unanswerable but the metric doesn't appear to correspond to a known critical value approach.

Comment: @M__ I tried to add more info and edit my questions to be more clear. Hope that helps, and let me know if you want me to add more info.